# Register/Login with Linkedin in ASP .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I am using ASP .NET Core 3.1 Individual Authentication Template for my web project. I am trying to integrate LinkedIn External Login but don't know how to do it properly.

I have used following link for help:
[OAuth LinkedIn Integration](https://auth0.com/blog/authenticating-a-user-with-linkedin-in-aspnet-core/)

**Here is my code:**

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddOAuth("LinkedIn", "LinkedIn", options =>
            {
                IConfigurationSection linkedinAuthNSection =
                Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Linkedin");

                options.ClientId = linkedinAuthNSection["ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = linkedinAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];

                options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-linkedin");
                options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization";
                options.TokenEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken";
                options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,formatted-name,email-address,picture-url)";
                options.Scope.Add("r_liteprofile");
                options.Scope.Add("r_emailaddress");
                options.Scope.Add("w_member_social");
            });
```

But i get error in `OnGetCallbackAsync` handler at:

```
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

value of `info` is received `null`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After trying multiple options i just found a github repo and nuget package for linkedin external login and it is working perfectly without any extra code just like Microsoft official documentation for Google and Facebook Login.

**My Code:**

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddLinkedIn(options =>
            {
                IConfigurationSection linkedinAuthNSection =
                Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Linkedin");

                options.ClientId = linkedinAuthNSection["ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = linkedinAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
            });
```

**Nuget Package:** [AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn/)

**Github Repo:** [AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers)

More then 60 providers integration is available including Instagarm, Dropbox, Soundcloud etc. Complete list available at github link.

Just replace `Providers` from `AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers` with your desired provider name. Some examples are:

**Instagram:** [AspNet.Security.OAuth.Instagram](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Instagram/)

**Dropbox:** [AspNet.Security.OAuth.Dropbox](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Dropbox/)

**Apple:** [AspNet.Security.OAuth.Apple](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Apple/)